# Can postgres-kit encode Swift Decimal type to a Postgres numeric column type?

Tags: sql, swift, postgresql, codable, vapor

I'm using [vapor/postgres-kit](https://github.com/vapor/postgres-kit) (and by extension [vapor/sql-kit](https://github.com/vapor/sql-kit)) to insert some `Codable` conformant Swift objects into a PostgreSQL table. Some of the Swift object properties are of type `Decimal`, which are being used to represent monetary values accurately where Float or Double do not otherwise work reliably. The Postgres columns that store these Swift `Decimal` types are of the Postgres type `numeric`, which is a great match for accuracy/precision.

The default `Encodable` conformance of `Decimal` results in a Swift `String`, which then arrives in the SQL statement as a quoted value, which causes Postgres to throw an error because it's not expecting a string value for a `numeric` column type.

As far as I can see from looking around inside the `SQLQueryEncoder` class, there's nowhere to hook in to instead produce a value of something like `SQLLiteral.numeric(String)`, which is a type that already exists in sql-kit.

My question is, can this be achieved somehow or do I need to abandon generating Inserts/Updates using Codable conformance in favour of manually forming queries in order to customise how the Decimal types are handled?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Currently no, but [this PR](https://github.com/vapor/postgres-nio/pull/194) should solve the issue